# Reactor and Spring state machine execute Mono then Flux sequentially

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-statemachine

I have the following method that is called the method does not have a return value but gets an object from another service metadataService that returns a Mono and then some processing is done with the object returned by the Mono, and once this is done I need to send a signal to the StateMachine so that next step can be triggered.

```
         public void safeExecute(
             StateContext<StateMachineStates, StateMachineEvents> context){
        metadataService.getMetadata(context.getId())
            .doOnSuccess(metadata ->{
              // perform some operation here

              context.getStateMachine()
             // returns a Flux<StateMachineEventResult<S, E>>   
             .sendEvent(Mono.just(
                  MessageBuilder.withPayload(Events.E_GOTO_NEXT_STATE).build()
                 ))
              .subscribe()
            })
           .
        }
```

I get however the warning :

`Calling 'subscribe' in non-blocking context is not recommended`

That I can apparently resolve by calling `publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())` however the warning is still there.

My question is how can you send the event to the StateMachine only after the code block within `onSuccess` is done? I tried using `concatWith` or `doFinally` but I do not have enough good understanding of reactive programming.

My current stack :

- Spring Boot 3.0.1
- Spring State Machine 3.0.1
- Spring 6

Comment: Where is this method called from, is it some Webflux Controller? How does the method that calls your method look like?

Comment: This method gets called as a Step of a StateMachine, that being said I would like if possible to know how to chain this no matter from where is called

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use subscribe here, your goal its to send the mono of the Message, you need to receive this message as a mono of your message somewhere, and there you would use the contents of it.

```
monoMessage.map(message -> doSomethingWithYourMessage(message))
```